# Selected feature disappears when selected again

Tags: editing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am having problem editing line layer with editor widget

1. If I click the selected feature for editing vertices  the
   selected features disappears sometimes
2. If I select the graphics
   and then select new selection from toolbar and select the already
   selected feature  it disappears.

I can't understand why its happening, below is jsfiddle code of the Editor widget with a polyline layer.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/b5a20ua8/

Comment: Hi, I opened your JSFiddle and am clicking the line, and it does not disappear for me. What browser are you using? What OS? Are you sure you're on a good internet connection?

Comment: @GavinR it's happening sometime(if it is already selected),  have too tried 2nd one because it is always happening

Comment: @GavinR I am using Chrome (latest version) , i tried it on firefox (latest version) same issue , window 8.1 and my internet connection is also good